# Apply a predicate on all elements of a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to update a list by applying a predicate function on every elements.

Here's how I would do it without using LINQ:

```
for(int i = 0; i < filesToCheck.Count; i++)
{
    while (filesToCheck[i][0] == '/' || filesToCheck[i][0] == '\\')
        filesToCheck[i] = filesToCheck[i].Substring(1);   
}
```

How can I do that with LINQ?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I just would like to have the same behavior as the code posted above but using LINQ, and I'm not very good with it.

Comment: The Q in LINQ stands for "query" - LINQ is generally for reading collections and projecting them, not modifying them.

Comment: How do you expect LINQ to help you here?

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought I could use LINQ to apply a predicate on every elements to update them. Sorry then..

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, I have to admit, that's a really good way of looking at this problem. LINQ isn't even the technology a person is looking for. Now, if you wanted to *filter the list* that's a different story.

Comment: I'm just asking because a lot of people tend to think: *throw LINQ at it, everything get's magically better.*

Comment: What is the problem with your loop which seems to be short, efficient and readable?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I presume you mean the `for` loop rather than the `while` loop :p

Comment: @Rawling: Yes :) He should use `TrimStart` instead.

Comment: There is a ForEach method that does just this, but it's only on `List<T>`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you need is to remove some characters from start of every fileName, you can use `TrimStart` for that, and then:

```
var list = filesToCheck.Select(f => f.TrimStart('/', '\\'));
```

EDIT: you could do this without LINQ, of course, but the main issue here is your `while` loop, rather than the use of `for`: it took me a few seconds to mentally parse the while loop to figure out what it does. This does not convey intent, I have to mentally execute it to understand it. Alternatively, you could rewrite it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < filesToCheck.Count; i++)
{
    filesToCheck[i] = GetValueWithoutSlashes(filesToCheck[i]);
}
```

then it would be clear to everyone reading this, and also allowing you to change implementation of `GetValueWithoutSlashes` to be whatever you want, e.g.

```
private string GetValueWithoutSlashes(string value)
{ 
    return value.TrimStart('/', '\\');
}
```

Comment: It's important to call out that unlike the code in the question which modifies the existing collection, this projects a new sequence.

Comment: This gives new query, it won't modify the elements. So OP needs to convert it to array and reassign it.

Comment: It's better to create a new collection in this case, rather modify strings in a tight loop, creating lots of garbage strings in the process.

Comment: @IgalTabachnik no one is debating that, but not everyone understands the functional difference.

Comment: Besides, this correctly conveys the purpose of the method, i.e. remove rooting characters from collection of filenames. The code of OP requires mentally parse the loop and figure out what's going on.

Comment: @IgalTabachnik Nothing wrong in your answer, but you need to educate OP that this is bit different, OP may/maynot be knowing it isn't it?

Comment: @IgalTabachnik It's possible to update the collection in-place while still using `TrimStart` to reduce the number of garbage strings.

Comment: I agree with you both, but I ALWAYS will prefer a function that conveys intent, than worry about some sort of optimization.

Comment: @IgalTabachnik: if you would show OP's for-loop but using `TrimStart` instead of the while-loop your answer would be ready to be accepted :)

Comment: Question was `How can I do that with LINQ?` TrimStart is the predicate function in this case. So the example is already sufficient. Also note his comment: `I just would like to have the same behavior as the code posted above but using LINQ, and I'm not very good with it.`

Comment: Thanks!
I used `filesToCheck = filesToCheck.Select(f => f.TrimStart('/', '\\')).ToList();`

Comment: @ApocKalipsS glad to help! SO can be an angry place, sometimes :)